# Jump with Ctrl-I doesn't work in my MacVim, but Ctrl-O works?

Tags: vim, macvim

Jump with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> doesn't work in my Vim, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> works.

It's weird, `verbose map <c-i>` or `verbose map <c-I>` shows below:

```
s  <Tab>         <Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger
    Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/vim-snipmate/after/plugin/snipMate.vim
x  <Tab>         >gv
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/settings/Settings.vim
n  <Tab>         v>
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugin/settings/Settings.vim
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>, the current line will be indented, and vim goes to Visual Mode.

I tried to add `unmap <c-i>` to ~/.gvimrc, but it failed, when macvim starts

```
Error detected while processing /Users/dfang/.vimrc:
line   83:
E31: No such mapping
```

How can I get back my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>, and how can I remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> (left from <kbd>=</kbd> key) ?

Comment: romainl has cleared it up. I just didn't know that `<C-i>` and `<Tab>` are equivalent.

Comment: It is possible to map `Tab` to an action and leave `Ctrl-i` alone in Xterm as described in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631241.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

1. `<C-i>` and `<Tab>` are strictly equivalent.
2. You are actively overriding `<Tab>` and therefore `<C-i>` in `~/.vim/plugin/settings/Settings.vim`.
3. If you want `<C-i>` to work normally don't override it (or `<Tab>`). Simple.
4. Unless you have a *very* specific reason to do so, you don't need to put anything in `~/.gvimrc`.
5. The normal place for your settings/mappings is `~/.vimrc`, there's no valid reason to put them anywhere else (`~/.vim/plugin/settings/Settings.vim` or wherever).
6. Use `nnoremap <C-+> <C-o>` if you want `<C-+>` to do what `<C-o>` does, whatever benefit you think you will get from doing that.

Answer (score 4):

Ye snipmate is adding the mapping.

Thanks @dfang. Based on your question

> I tried to add unmap `<c-i>` to ~/.gvimrc, but it failed, when macvim
>   starts

I tried to use `<C-i>` instead and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to press Ctrl-Shift-i (also Ctrl-Shift-o) instead.

Older keyboards did not have the TAB key so Ctrl-I was used for that purpose, but for vim, it seems we can take advantage of this:

```
Ctrl-i == TAB
Ctrl-Shift-i != Shift-TAB
```