# <C-I> mapped incorrectly in macvim

Tags: vim, macvim

I was trying to navigate the jump list in MacVim and I noticed that `<C-I>` doesn't work, although it works fine in normal Vim.

In insert mode, pressing `<C-V><C-I>` gives `<D-<89>>`. `<C-V><Tab>` gives `^I`. (In normal vim (not MacVim), doing the same yields `^[` and `^I`, respectively.)

My first thought was to check if I had a mapping set.

output of `:map`

```
x  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis
n  gx            <Plug>NetrwBrowseX
x  <Plug>NetrwBrowseXVis * :<C-U>call netrw#BrowseXVis()<CR>
n  <Plug>NetrwBrowseX * :call netrw#BrowseX(netrw#GX(),netrw#CheckIfRe
mote(netrw#GX()))<CR>
```

output of `:map!`

```
No mapping found.
```

I saw mentioned on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175647/jump-with-ctrl-i-doesnt-work-in-my-macvim-but-ctrl-o-works) that `<Tab>` and `<C-I>` are mirrored. But I don't have a mapping for `<Tab>` anywhere as you can see above.

I'm stuck at this point. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, `<C-v><C-i>` should just produce a simple `<Tab>` (U+0009), definitely not `<D-<89>>` or `<D-<anything>>` for that matter.

In `<D-<89>>`,

- `<D-` is the notation for the Command key,
- and `<89>` is the notation for ["Character Tabulation with Justification"](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0089).

`U+0089` seems vaguely related to `U+0009` so that would be one thing to investigate, but the combination with the `Command` key is weird.

If I were you I would open an issue in MacVim's issue tracker.

Comment: I would be curious to know how you solved your problem.

Comment: I've added the bandaid mapping for now: `nnoremap <D-<89>> <TAB>`

Answer (score 0):

Oops, it turns out I had a hardware keybinding overwriting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>. In Vim this resulted in `<C-i>` because it was discarding the extra <kbd>cmd</kbd> and <kbd>option</kbd> keys.